# Using ng-show directive to toggle multiple elements?

Tags: angularjs

Say I've got a `<nav>` element with three buttons, and an `<article>` containing three `<section>` elements.  I want a user to be able to click a button, which toggles the display of all of the `<section>` elements in such a way that only the one relevant `<section>` is shown.

---

[image]

---

I'm new to AngularJS and trying to figure out if theres a more Angularly way of achieving this than by giving the nav elements `ng-click` attributes and the `section` elements the `ng-show` attribute. It feels very imperative.

My HTML would look something like this:

```
<nav>
    <div ng-click="showRedSection()"></div>
    <div ng-click="showBlueSection()"></div> //etc.
<nav>

<article>
    <section ng-show="redSectionShown">
       // content; etc.
    </section>
    //etc.
</article>
```

Am I on the right track, or is there an approach that makes this more declarative?

Comment: do you need to hide the other 2 sections when you display one ? , if so , try ngSwitch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are going is correct.

Instead of needing a function to toggle the value on click you could do `redSectionShown = !!redSectionShown`

Or if you have a lot of sections and other data you want to store create a service to store the visible state of the regions and create directive that can toggle the values or use the values to hide elements.

The second approach reduces your $scope pollution.

```
.service('ViewableRegions', function() {
    var viewablePropertiesMap = {};
    this.getValue = function(value) {
        return viewablePropertiesMap[value];
    }
    this.setValue = function(valueToUpdate, value) {
        viewablePropertiesMap[valueToUpdate] = value
    }
})
```

Directive to toggle region visability

```
.directive('regionToggler', function(ViewableRegions) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            compile: function($element, $attrs) {
                var directiveName = this.name;
                var valueToUpdate = attrs[directiveName];

                return function(scope, element, attrs) {
                    element.on('click', function() {
                        var currentValue = ViewableRegions.getValue(ViewableRegions);
                        ViewableRegions.setValue(valueToUpdate, !!currentValue);
                        scope.$apply();
                    })
                };
            }
        };
    }
);
```

Directive to display the regions

```
.directive('regionDisplayer', function(ViewableRegions) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            compile: function($element, $attrs) {
                var directiveName = this.name;
                var valueToUpdate = attrs[directiveName];

                return function(scope, element, attrs) {
                    scope.$watch(
                        function() {
                            return ViewableRegions.getValue(ViewableRegions);
                        },
                        function(newVal) {
                            if (newVal) {
                                element[0].style.display = "none";
                            } else {
                                element[0].style.display = "";
                            }
                        }
                    )
                };
            }
        };
    }
);
```

HTML Uasge
    
        
         //etc.

```
<article>
    <section region-displayer="redSectionShown">
       // content; etc.
    </section>
    //etc.
</article>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would actually recommend trying to use ng-hide as opposed to ng-show. These directives complete the same task most of the time,but ng-hide defaults to a hidden state, where you can then setup parameters in which the information will be shown. I ran into a similar problem with an app I was working on in angular, and using ng-hide seemed to help simplify the code in my view.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
<div ng-click="sectionToShow=1"></div>
<div ng-click="sectionToShow=2"></div>

<article>
    <section ng-show="sectionToShow==1"></section>
</article>
```

I haven't tested this, but there's no reason it shouldn't work. That way, you will automatically only ever show the correct section, and all other sections will auto hide themselves.